# Symfony 2: data lost from non-mapped field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

My Symfony2 form has an underlying data structure, but in my form I have some extra fields which are declared as non-mapped.  I assign data to them when adding them to the form:

```
$form->add('cell_0_1', 'textarea', array(
    'data'     => $connection->outputCellData($col, $recordsDoc, $records->item($rowNo), true), 
    'mapped'   => false,
    'required' => false
));
```

I then display these fields, passing the result of applying createView() to my form:

```
return $this->render(
    'ModesBundle:Modes:editgrid.html.twig',
    array(
        'toolbar'    => $toolbarForm->createView(),
        'records'    => $recs,
        'connection' => $connection,
        'navigator'  => $connection->navigator,
    )
);
```

The non-mapped fields can be displayed on my form, but the data which I assigned to them has gone missing. My twig template contains e.g.:

```
<td>{{ form_widget(toolbar.cell_0_1) }}</td>
```

Is this expected behaviour? My handler is as follows:

```
public function browserAction(Request $request, $action) {
    $connection = $this->getModesConnection();
    $toolbarForm = $this->getToolbarForm($request, $connection);
    $this->prepareEdit($toolbarForm, 'update-termlist', $connection);
    $this->updateFormWithConnectionSettings($connection, $toolbarForm, 'update-termlist');
    $this->updateFormWithGrid($toolbarForm, $connection);
    $toolbarForm->handleRequest($request);
    switch ($connection->getAction()) {
      ...
        case 'edit':
            switch ($connection->getView()) {
                ...
                case 'grid':
                    $recs = $connection->getEditGrid($toolbarForm);
                    return $this->render('ModesBundle:Modes:editgrid.html.twig',
                        array('toolbar' => $toolbarForm->createView(), 'records'=> $recs, 'connection' => $connection, 'navigator' => $connection->navigator, ));
                    break;
```

$toolbarForm has all my non-mapped grid cell fields, but they have their data values set to null (modelData, normData) or an empty string (viewData) at some point during the command:

```
    $toolbarForm->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how "but the data which I assigned to them has gone missing" is manifesting. Are you saying that when the textarea renders, the default value is not what you expect? Are you sure `$connection->outputCellData()` is returning something?

Comment: Peter, thanks, I'll check outputCellData(), but what I meant is that the textarea appears but is empty. I would expect it to be populated with the data I had assigned to that form element.

Comment: As it should :) Can you double check the return value of `$connection->outputCellData()`?

Comment: See updated problem statement. If I remove the handleRequest line, or put it after the rendering logic, the textarea fields display with their data still intact. Thanks for the comments and support.